# How to avoid clashing PHP traits used for dependency injection

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, traits

I'm finally getting around to exploring traits in PHP. The first place I thought I'd try it out is injection of config bits into classes. If I'm using DIC, I might have code like this in any class that needs a config object:

```
protected function SetConfig($config) {
    $this->config = $config;
}

protected $config;
```

This seems like a natural fit to traits to avoid having that boilerplate code all over the place, so I might create this:

```
trait Config {
    protected function SetConfig($config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    protected $config;
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
class Foo {
    use Config;

    public function __construct() {
        //can now use $this->config
    }
}
```

That's great. Now let's say I want to create a second trait, say, for logging:

```
trait Logger {
    protected function SetLogger($logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected $logger;
}
```

Which I can use like this:

```
class Foo {
    use Logger;

    public function __construct() {
        //can now use $this->logger
    }
}
```

Also great. Now the problem comes if those two traits want to use each other. It seems quite reasonable that a logger class would need to have a config object injected, which means doing this:

```
trait Logger {
    use Config;

    protected function SetLogger($logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected $logger;
}
```

But then things will break when another class uses both of these traits:

```
class Foo {
    use Config, Logger;

    public function __construct() {
        //want to use $this->config and $this->logger
    }
}
```

This, of course, doesn't work because the config bits are effectively duplicated in Foo.

I could just leave out the `use Config;` piece from the Logger trait, knowing that it'll be there in the end. But this feels weird to me as it creates a sort of external dependency. What if I want to use the Logger someplace that didn't already have the config trait? This solution also means I need to suffer my IDE (PhpStorm 8) warning me about unknown methods, and not offering autocompletion. I realize I could fix these problems in turn by using @method, but that's just putting lipstick on a pig, so to speak.

I could also alias the config bits in Logger, but that's also problematic.

All of this has a bit of a smell to it, but I haven't figured out yet whether that's because this is a new pattern for me or if it really is a stinky pattern. Either way, I'm not sure the best way to make this approach actually work.

Any advice on the best way to solve this problem in traits? Or is it better to avoid traits for DIC shortcutting?

Comment: Never used `traits` for DI myself, but one suggestion I could make is that if you have traits that require other traits you may benefit from turning them into classes instead.

Comment: A logger trait may need the config to know what logging level to use or where to write the log files. But really, the question is about more than just this case - this is just an example. More broadly, it's certainly not uncommon to have dependencies among core bits of functionality. When using the boilerplate code (property and setter) in every class, this isn't an issue, but it's an issue with traits. In this case, adding `use Config` to Logger won't work because the class that uses both Logger and Config (above, Foo) will generate fatal errors because the pieces from Config are duplicated.

Comment: That's why I asked the question. As I said, it has a funny smell, but at the same time, traits seem like a great approach to solving the boilerplate problem inherent in DI. So what's the best approach to putting the two together?

Comment: I think that "use Trait" should work more like require_once. Since traits are flattened anyway there is no harm in ignoring the duplicity and just throwing one of them away. The fatal error in this case seems too draconic to me.

Comment: More on this here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61943

Answer (score 3):

The method I've found useful is using getters as well as setters. This then allows you to require that a specific getter exists, without conflicting with other traits.

```
trait Config {
    protected function SetConfig($config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    protected function GetConfig() {
        return $this->config;
    }

    protected $config;
}

trait Logger {
    abstract protected function GetConfig();

    protected function SetLogger($logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected $logger;
}

class Baz {
    use Config, Logger;

    // ...

}
```

In Baz, the Config trait provides the required abstract method and Baz is composed without error. If you mistakenly only use Logger you will get a Fatal Error: Class Baz contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Baz::GetConfig)

Comment: This does get the job done, though it's not ideal. The main things that bug me about it are: 1) documentation gets messy (e.g., if one just sees Logger, how does one know where GetConfig() is supposed to come from?) 2) One has to use Config to use Logger, which is a weird external dependency that, again, is hard to document, and 3) this also relates to documentation, but how does one (*can* one?) annotate it properly with PHPDoc so that IDE code completion and refactoring work? Points for a solution that gets the job done, but it would be great to have a truly clean way to do this.

Comment: As a followup, I realize that reservations 1 and 3 will likely be addressed in a phpDocumentor update to better handle traits, if they've not, in fact, already been addressed. But I don't see a solution coming to 2. Explicitly requiring the client class to know that Config must be used if Logger is used is going to get messy no matter what, I think. I can see it working well in some well-defined cases, but in this case, Config and Logger just feel to me like they should be reusable "bricks" on their own. Then again, if it's unlikely a class will ever use Logger but not Config....

Comment: Do you know any IDE that flow between traits? When I click on $this->getConfig, the IDE goes to the abstract definition, not to the method definition in trait Config. Maybe a phpdoc that helps IDE to do it?

Comment: The abstract method only has a concrete implementation when it is composed into a class that implements that method. There could be multiple implementations. The closest you will get would be to link to the expected provider with an @see doc block (e.g. annotating the Logger trait's GetConfig method with `@see Config::GetConfig` in the example code.)